Text warp with box
How can I wrap text in a frame like this using LaTeX/KaTeX?

Note: Question about using [tag:katex] are off-topic. So you should limit the question to LaTeX (and usually the answers would be LaTeX answers). KaTeX question can be asked on Stack OverFlow instead (see also the tag information of the first link).

Looks like a \tcbox{...} from the tcolorbox package:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


: \tcbox[nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,size=small,colframe=lightgray]{-1} .

\end{document}


